# Extracted Arabic data from excel file turn into questions marks

Tags: java, encoding

I have a program written in Java that reads an excel file and output the cell's content in the Java output console ,this excel file contains arabic data.

The program work well but some arabic letters and  arabic numbers displayed as "question marks"
/ "?" in the Java data output.

I think it is encoding problem.So,is there a function I can add to specify the encoding in the Java program...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didnt shared your code I will post how to read arabic string in java, we will use:

```
String arabicText = testObject.getArabicText(); 
arabicText = new String(arabicText.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF-8"); 
System.out.println("Arabic Text :  "+arabicText);
```

Hope you can make changes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways two get correct data from excel file

1. Go to Windows - Preferences - General - expand menu - Workspace - Change Text File encoding at bottom and apply
2. Right click to Package Name - Properties - Change Text File Encoding formats